# rom-rb form validation when using multiple relations

Tags: ruby, ruby-object-mapper, rom-rb

I'm trying out http://rom-rb.org/ and can't figure out how to get a presence validation to pass in the presence of multiple source models. I would expect the following script to save a new event and organiser, but instead it says that `event_name` is not present.

What am I missing?

```
require 'bundler/inline'

gemfile do
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  gem 'rom'
  gem 'rom-sql'
  gem 'rom-rails'
  gem 'activemodel'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'activesupport'
end

require 'rom'
require 'rom-rails'

`rm -Rf /tmp/romtest.sqlite`
ROM.setup(:sql, 'sqlite:///tmp/romtest.sqlite')

class Events < ROM::Relation[:sql]
end

class Organisers < ROM::Relation[:sql]
end

class CreateEvent < ROM::Commands::Create[:sql]
  relation :events
  register_as :create
  result :one

  associates :organiser, key: [:organiser_id, :id]
end

class CreateOrganiser < ROM::Commands::Create[:sql]
  relation :organisers
  register_as :create
  result :one
end

class CreateEventWithOrganiser < ROM::Model::Form
  commands organisers: :create, events: :create

  input do
    attribute :email
    attribute :event_name
  end

  validations do
    validates :event_name, presence: true
  end

  def commit!
    command = organisers.create.with(
      email: email,
    ) >> events.create.with(
      name: event_name,
    )

    command.transaction do
      command.call
    end
  end
end

ROM.finalize
rom = ROM.env
gateway = rom.gateways.fetch(:default)
migration = gateway.migration do
  change do
    create_table :organisers do
      primary_key :id
      column :email, String, null: false
    end

    create_table :events do
      primary_key :id
      column :name, String, null: false
      column :organiser_id, Integer, null: false
    end
  end
end

migration.apply(gateway.connection, :up)

f = CreateEventWithOrganiser.build(
  email:      'test@example.com',
  event_name: 'Test Event'
)

# Unexpectedly fails
f.save
puts f.errors.full_messages
# => "Event name can't be blank"
```

Comment: I can make this work by explicitly calling `validate!; return false unless success?` at the top of `commit!`. Is that the intended API?

Comment: From reading the source I also think I want `inject_commands_for :events, :organisers` rather than `commands organisers: :create, events: :create`, though this method does not appear in the guides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an updated version of your script which works:

```
require 'rom'
require 'rom-rails'

`rm -Rf /tmp/romtest.sqlite`
ROM.setup(:sql, 'sqlite:///tmp/romtest.sqlite')

class Events < ROM::Relation[:sql]
end

class Organisers < ROM::Relation[:sql]
end

class CreateEvent < ROM::Commands::Create[:sql]
  relation :events
  register_as :create
  result :one

  associates :organiser, key: [:organiser_id, :id]
end

class CreateOrganiser < ROM::Commands::Create[:sql]
  relation :organisers
  register_as :create
  result :one
end

class CreateEventWithOrganiser < ROM::Model::Form
  inject_commands_for :organisers, :events

  input do
    attribute :email
    attribute :event_name
  end

  validations do
    validates :event_name, presence: true
  end

  def commit!
    validate!

    return if errors.any?

    command = organisers.create.with(
      email: email
    ) >> events.create.with(
      name: event_name
    )

    command.transaction do
      command.call
    end
  end
end

ROM.finalize
rom = ROM.env
gateway = rom.gateways.fetch(:default)
migration = gateway.migration do
  change do
    create_table :organisers do
      primary_key :id
      column :email, String, null: false
    end

    create_table :events do
      primary_key :id
      column :name, String, null: false
      column :organiser_id, Integer, null: false
    end
  end
end

migration.apply(gateway.connection, :up)

f = CreateEventWithOrganiser.build(
  email:      'test@example.com',
  event_name: 'Test Event'
)

puts f.save.result.inspect
# #<ROM::Commands::Result::Success:0x007fa92b589ea0 @value={:id=>1, :name=>"Test Event", :organiser_id=>1}>
```

The reason why it didn't work with `commands` is because this method will generate command objects for your form and set provided validations for each command, which will only work correctly if you used a single command. Otherwise same validator is used for each command which doesn't make sense. When you use `inject_commands_for` it will grab your own commands where validators are not set so you are free to handle validations yourself.

I think we should stop setting validators on commands which would make your original sample work but notice that you need to call `validate!` yourself.

I hope this helps.

I also created a gist showing how to do the same without a form: https://gist.github.com/solnic/3b68342482cf1414f719

Comment: thank you! The example without the form really helped me understand how things fit together :)